# How to get a C# Windows Form DropDownList to behave like a browser drop down list?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, match

I have a ComboBox in DropDownList mode. Say the contents are:

1
2
5
91
92
99
205

In the Forms application, I want to be able to focus on the control and type 205 and have it select 205. Instead, I press 2 - it jumps to 2. I press 0, nothing starts with 0, so it stays on 2. I press 5, it jumps to 5. It's only looking at the last key I pressed.

Same if I type 99, it jumps to the first 9 match - 91, then to the second 9 match - 92. But I wanted it to go to 99.

On the other hand, in any browser if you are on a dropdown and type in a sequence of characters, it will consider them all together and jump to a full match. (Same behavior in Windows folders if you type a file name.) The sequence usually resets after a few seconds of no typing.

How can I get my forms dropdown to behave like a browser dropdown?

Comment: You need an `autocompletebox` rather than a `combobox` - you'll need a 3rd party control - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/AutoCompleteComboBox.aspx perhaps?

Comment: Try setting DropDownStyle to DropDown

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the AutoCompleteMode to Suggest, AutoCompleteSource to ListItems and the Style to DropDownList.

Comment: Thank you! I knew there had to be an easy way.

Answer (score 1):

I would also add that you need to set the "FlatStyle" property to "Popup" to make it more like the Web combobox.

Comment: Please use "Comments" section for comments. Thanks!